# How to build Liferay 7 WSRP module?

Tags: gradle, ant, build, liferay-7, wsrp

I am trying to build Liferay 7 wsrp module from Liferay GitHub repository. 
I couldn't build entire Liferay source, is it possible to build this [wsrp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7.0.1-ga2/modules/apps/wsrp) module only ?

If anybody has a jar file working on Liferay 7 CE ga2 or ga3, please share.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important Edit:**

You don't actually need to rely on the Liferay Portal jars for most modules. The reason this one failed as it did was that simply running `gradlew deploy` in `modules/apps/wsrp` will automatically include all subprojects, which includes wsrp-test. The "-test" modules rely on the com.liferay.portal.test-integration artifact.

However, if you add the option `-Dbuild.profile=portal` to your command, the Gradle wrapper liferay-portal will only include modules that contain the .lfrbuild-portal marker file, which all of the wsrp modules have except for wsrp-test.

**Original Post:**

Liferay has a Maven repository that hosts their public artifacts.

Their portal artifacts can be found here: https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/

However, if you're building a module from the source in their Git repo, the latest release/snapshot on the Maven repo might be out of date. Snapshots are updated fairly frequently, but this is still a possibility. The safest thing to do is to just compile the portal from source.

Comment: Thanks @CAusting, i could able to build the wrsp module using gradle deploy command in modules/apps/wsrp, after deploying this jars to ce-7-ga3, i am getting below error. any idea how can i resolve it.                                     Could not resolve module: com.liferay.wsrp.service [491]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.expando.kernel.util; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"